# Is there a way to truncate a Pandas DataFrame so that its length is equal to that of another DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've searched everywhere for the answer, but most solutions require many steps and are unneccessary complicated. Is there a relatively compact way to shorten the length of a Pandas DataFrama to match the length of another? (I want it to cut excess values from the top)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming `df1` is current data frame and `df2` is the new smaller dataframe,

```
df1_truncated= df1.tail(len(df2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just curious, what is the difference between using len(df) and len(df.index) ?

Comment: @user10650761 No difference, both will give the same length. len(df.index) is slightly faster infact!

Answer (score 1):

For remove rows from top use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with indexing:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(5)})   
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':range(10, 23)})

df3 = df2.iloc[-len(df1):]
print (df3)
     b
8   18
9   19
10  20
11  21
12  22
```